# looping through json response in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, response

I am using `json_decode` with `TRUE` to parse a json response in PHP, but when I try to access its elements, it is not working, Here is how the response looks like

```
BCLS.secondaryCallResponse({"items":[{"id":4377466391001,"name":"Sample Video 2","creationDate":"1438012370879","renditions":[{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":798000,"frameHeight":360,"frameWidth":640,"id":109379493001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":2987928,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422604020,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379493001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29967},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":271000,"frameHeight":180,"frameWidth":320,"id":109379483001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1013553,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422590621,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379483001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29960},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":1746000,"frameHeight":720,"frameWidth":1280,"id":109379494001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":6538469,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422604397,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379494001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29967},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":413000,"frameHeight":180,"frameWidth":320,"id":109379449001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1547446,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422544580,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379449001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29960},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":1167000,"frameHeight":360,"frameWidth":640,"id":109379422001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":4370827,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422465338,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379422001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29967},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":517000,"frameHeight":268,"frameWidth":480,"id":109379402001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1937694,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422444109,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379402001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29967}]},{"id":4377466392001,"name":"Sample Video 1","creationDate":"1438012370884","renditions":[{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":730000,"frameHeight":360,"frameWidth":640,"id":207397055001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":752301,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774725742,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397055001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":1791000,"frameHeight":720,"frameWidth":1280,"id":207397050001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1844840,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774712658,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397050001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":107000,"frameHeight":224,"frameWidth":400,"id":207397051001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":110856,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774725067,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397051001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8267},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":446000,"frameHeight":268,"frameWidth":480,"id":207397052001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":459435,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774725177,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397052001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":1117000,"frameHeight":404,"frameWidth":720,"id":207397049001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1151256,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774712501,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397049001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":252000,"frameHeight":224,"frameWidth":400,"id":207397056001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":259671,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774725855,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397056001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242}]}],"page_number":0,"page_size":2,"total_count":-1});
```

$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE); // should convert it to array

I am then accessing,`$responseData[0]` and it displays `B` only, Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: `$responseData['items'][0]`

Comment: Your actual `json` response start from `{"items`. So your encoded json string is `$response = {"items....,"total_count:-1"}`...

Comment: the response starts with BCLS.secondaryCallResponse( ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices :

1) convert to associate array - `$json = json_decode('{"items":[ ...', true)` :

```
foreach ($json['items'] as $item) {
    //for example, show first rendition for each item
    print_r($item['renditions'][0]);
}
```

2) convert to stdClasses - `$json = json_decode('{"items":[ ...')` :

```
foreach ($json->items as $item) {
    //for example, show first rendition for each item
    print_r($item->renditions[0]);
}
```

Comment: the response starts with BCLS.secondaryCallResponse( , none of your stated example works

Comment: @UsmanSm,  `BCLS.secondaryCallResponse()` is the clientside javascript call to the server  - it is this function ->  **https://github.com/BrightcoveLearning/BCL-Solutions/blob/master/media/VideoDataToCSV/renditions-size-in-csv.html#L294**

Comment: @davidkonard I tried your solution and it doesnt work, you can try here http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: @UsmanSm, well - created a phpfiddle account and it works there too - I just cannot figure out how to share a link to the fiddle, havent used phpfiddle before. But still, you must realize that `BCLS.secondaryCallResponse()` is the clientside javascript and you are on the serverside, trying to parse the JSON that call is passing.

Comment: @david, yes - but as suggested several times - `BCLS.secondaryCallResponse()` is something you have copied from a clientside script and the JSON is not valid. The JSON you need to parse is between `( ... )` so remove `BCLS.secondaryCallResponse(` and `)` ...

Comment: That is very bad from them if they are sending useless info, as I have to write additional substring etc function to remove this. Let me try

Comment: @david - `BCLS.secondaryCallResponse()` is not even valid PHP, it is javascript and would crash your script if it was executed, I have already refered to where it come from above -> https://github.com/BrightcoveLearning/BCL-Solutions/blob/master/media/VideoDataToCSV/renditions-size-in-csv.html#L294

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
        $data='{"items":[{"id":4377466391001,"name":"Sample Video 2","creationDate":"1438012370879","renditions":[{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":798000,"frameHeight":360,"frameWidth":640,"id":109379493001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":2987928,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422604020,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379493001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29967},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":271000,"frameHeight":180,"frameWidth":320,"id":109379483001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1013553,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422590621,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379483001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29960},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":1746000,"frameHeight":720,"frameWidth":1280,"id":109379494001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":6538469,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422604397,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379494001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29967},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":413000,"frameHeight":180,"frameWidth":320,"id":109379449001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1547446,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422544580,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379449001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29960},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":1167000,"frameHeight":360,"frameWidth":640,"id":109379422001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":4370827,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422465338,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379422001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29967},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Redpoll","encodingRate":517000,"frameHeight":268,"frameWidth":480,"id":109379402001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1937694,"uploadTimestampMillis":1278422444109,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_109379402001_Bird-CommonRedpoll-iStock-000006369683HD720.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":29967}]},{"id":4377466392001,"name":"Sample Video 1","creationDate":"1438012370884","renditions":[{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":730000,"frameHeight":360,"frameWidth":640,"id":207397055001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":752301,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774725742,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397055001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":1791000,"frameHeight":720,"frameWidth":1280,"id":207397050001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1844840,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774712658,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397050001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":107000,"frameHeight":224,"frameWidth":400,"id":207397051001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":110856,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774725067,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397051001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8267},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":446000,"frameHeight":268,"frameWidth":480,"id":207397052001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":459435,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774725177,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397052001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":1117000,"frameHeight":404,"frameWidth":720,"id":207397049001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":1151256,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774712501,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397049001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242},{"audioOnly":false,"controllerType":"DEFAULT","displayName":"Sample Asset Titmouse","encodingRate":252000,"frameHeight":224,"frameWidth":400,"id":207397056001,"referenceId":null,"remoteStreamName":null,"remoteUrl":null,"size":259671,"uploadTimestampMillis":1279774725855,"url":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/uds\/pd\/96980657001\/96980657001_207397056001_Bird-Titmouse-iStock-000005422648HD1080.mp4","videoCodec":"H264","videoContainer":"MP4","videoDuration":8242}]}],"page_number":0,"page_size":2,"total_count":-1}';
        $sample=json_decode($data);
        var_dump($sample->items);
```

Comment: the response starts with BCLS.secondaryCallResponse( , none of your stated example works